# Web browser that stores credentials by host+path, not by the host part alone

Tags: android, web-browser, password-manager, url

I am looking for an Android browser *that is not from Google*, but which allows me to store the credentials for a website by host+path, not just host.

Effectively [this ticket on Bugzilla@Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=263387) tells the story of Firefox not offering the feature. I checked it for the Android version of Firefox and indeed it doesn't offer it.

Dolphin also does not offer it. When I save one set of credentials it behaves even so stupid that it inserts the password from one path as the username (so no obfuscation by showing only `*******`) on another form for another path.

So what I need is a browser that will happily store two separate sets of credentials for

- `https://example.net/someapp/` (`https://example.net/someapp/**` if we used shell globs)
- `https://example.net/anotherapp/` (`https://example.net/anotherapp/**` if we used shell globs)

Both, Dolphin and Firefox will allow only a single set of credentials here, as they are storing the passwords per host.